# How can I split the data in 40% training, 30% validation and 30% test

Tags: python

This is what I coded. I am able to create the permutation and create the three variables that I need training, validation and test. I can't just figure out how to split the data in the percentages mentioned above. In few words, when I create those variables they should be created accordingly and then have to print the result. Thanks in advance

```
def split_data(data_dict, data_split):
    """divide the data into training, validate and test sets. 
    :param data_dict: a dictionary of the data with keys 'X' and 'Y'
    :param data_split: a list of the fraction of the data to be in each set of form 
    [training_fraction, validation_fraction, test_fraction]. The fractions should all add up to 1.
    :returns training_dict, validation_dict, test_dict: dictionaries of the same form as the data_dict, 
    containing the different sets"""
    
    assert np.sum(data_split)-1 < 0.01
    
    # work out how many datapoints will be in the train and validation sets 
    n_train = int(len((data_dict['X']))*data_split[0])
    n_validate = int(len((data_dict['X']))*data_split[1])
    
    # generate a random permutation of indices of the data and split into training, validation and test
    perm = np.random.permutation(range(len(data_dict['X'])))
    indices_train, indices_validate, indices_test = np.split(perm, [n_train, n_train+ n_validate])
    
    # create training, validation and test dictionaries 
    training_dict = {'X': data['X'][indices_train], 'Y': data['Y'][indices_train]}
    validation_dict = {'X': data['X'][indices_validate], 'Y': data['Y'][indices_validate]}
    test_dict = {'X': data['X'][indices_test], 'Y': data['Y'][indices_test]}
    
    return training_dict, validation_dict, test_dict
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the specific issue you are facing?

Comment: I am not able to split the data in those percentages. I can't figure out how to tell python to split the variables accordingly when I do the perm function

Comment: I don't see a problem with this.  Does `split_data(data_dict, [0.4, 0.3, 0.3])` not do what you want?

Comment: How can I use this fucntion?

Answer (score 0):

Your `indices_train` etc. are lists of indices which you want to create subarrays from. Use `np.take`:

```
# create training, validation and test dictionaries 
training_dict = {'X': np.take(data_dict['X'], indices_train), 'Y': np.take(data_dict['Y'], indices_train)}
validation_dict = {'X': np.take(data_dict['X'], indices_validate), 'Y': np.take(data_dict['Y'], indices_validate)}
test_dict = {'X': np.take(data_dict['X'], indices_test), 'Y': np.take(data_dict['Y'], indices_test)}
```

Additionally, `data` was replaced with `data_dict`.

Comment: How would I split the data in the percentage mentioned pls?

Answer (score 0):

When I have to split a dataset like this, I usually use `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` function.
It will take a dataset and split it into train and validation sets.  There will be one set to train the model with, one set to fit your model against, one set to use as test data and one set to use as test answers.
The training data in the snippet below is called `xtrain`.
The set your model should be fit to is `ytrain`.
The set you can use as test data is called `xtest` and you can check how your model is doing and get scores by using the set called `ytest`.
All of these sets are the same shape that your input was.  There are different behaviors you can get out of `train_test_split` but the standard one is probably using it in default mode, which gives you a random sample of indices and the `Y` values' indices are kept in line with their respective `X` values, so you don't need to manage them, you just specify how big you want the test set to be; i.e. The percentage of your data do you want to train with vs test with.

here's *some* official docs on the function https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
...
def split_data(data_dict, data_split_percentage):
    assert data_split <= 100 # make sure we're dealing with percentage
    test_size = (data_split_percentage/100.0) # get [0.0,1.0] float
    xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(data_dict['X'],
                                                    data_dict['Y'],
                                                    test_size=test_size)
    return xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest

# Use your function to fit a model then assert results are == answers
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = split_data(data_dict, 70)
model = ModelClass.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
estimates = model.estimate(xtest)

for i,estimate in enumerate(estimates):
    assert estimate == ytrain[i]
```